# Manipulating attributes of NurbsPath

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to manipulate the property `bevel_factor_start` of a NURBS Curve. The following Python code works as expected.

```
bpy.data.curves['NurbsPath'].bevel_factor_start = .5
```

Is there a AN node that can be used to set this property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the Curve Object Output node has several hidden inputs including Bevel Start and Bevel End. Nice Work!